# how to display unique records between two table by using db_select query in drupal

Tags: forms, database

The following two tables contained `reg_no` field. how to get unique `reg_no` records of the `student_master` table

**for example**

student_master table

**reg_no**

MA1001

MA1002

**semester_appear** table

**reg_no**

MA1001

but I want to get output only **MA1002**. how to get the output by using following code

**Table : **Student Master****

```
$query = db_select('student_master');
$query->fields('student_master', array('reg_no','name','dob','dept_code','degree','batch_year'));
$query->condition('dept_code',$dept,'=') AND $query->condition('batch_year',$batch,'=');
$query->orderBy('reg_no','ASC') ;
$results = $query->execute();
```

**Table : semester_appear**

```
$sem_query = db_select('semester_appear');
$sem_query->fields('semester_appear', array('reg_no','batch_year','month','year','subject_code','sub_serial_no','semester_appear'));
$sem_query->distinct();
$sem_query->condition('year',$year,'=') AND $sem_query->condition('reg_no',$reg1,'=') AND $sem_query->condition('semester_appear',$semester,'=') AND $sem_query->condition('month',$month,'=') AND $sem_query->condition('marks_updated',$no,'=') AND $sem_query->condition('batch_year',$batch,'=') ;
$subject_results = $sem_query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the easiest way to do complex MySQL queries (including JOIN, which is what you're after here) is to use db_query():
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7

And the MySQL docs explain the JOIN syntax quite nicely:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html